# I want to work on spring projects

Tags: spring

I'm new to spring framework.I want to find a job which needs spring skill set.Should i learn all the modules of spring or one-two modules likes spring mvc and spring security are enough?Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with spring mvc as it requires some basic configuration and understanding what possibilities dependency injection / core spring features give you. It will quite shortly give you some visual effect which is helpful at beginning. Then you can secure your pages or api with spring security.. but it will probably require database, so you will mix in spring data...

So - start from some basic web application - it will drive you through basics of spring stack.